# Relation between the number of halfspaces and the number of vertices of a convex polytope

Tags: algebraic-geometry, convex-analysis, polytopes, locally-convex-spaces

Suppose we have  an $n$-dimensional convex polytope $\mathbf{P}$ represented by an intersection of half-spaces as the following:
\begin{equation} \mathbf{P} = \{ x \in \mathbb{R}^n \mid x \in \bigcap_{i=1}^K H_i \} \end{equation}
Then let's say that the set of all vertices of $\mathbf{P}$ is given by $V=(v_1,v_2,\ldots,v_N)$.
How we can find the relation between the number of halfspaces (i.e. $K$) and the number of vertices ($N$) of $\mathbf{P}$ ?

Thank you!

Comment: See [this question](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/127423/how-many-vertices-can-a-convex-polytope-have).

Comment: @Théophile I think that in this question they give the max number of vertices if we have $K$ halfspaces. In my case, I am looking for an exact relation bewteen $K$ and $N$ ..

Comment: The reason there's a maximum is that it depends on the polytope. An octahedron, for example, doesn't achieve the maximum because there are too many faces at each vertex, as it were. On the other hand, every prism in $\mathbb R^3$ does achieve the maximum.

Comment: Also consider the case where some half-spaces are redundant, i.e., the polytope lies strictly within their interior. You can have arbitrarily many half-spaces for any number of vertices. For that matter, the intersection of half-spaces might be empty.